# Grails 3 domain class composition

Tags: grails, dns, composition

With Grails 3.2.5, hibernate 5.1.2 core.

I have a legacy database that has several clobs in a table.  In order to avoid eager fetching, in earlier versions of Grails I defined a domain class that contained only those clobs in order to make them accessed via an (apparent) association which could then be lazily fetched.  A sketch of the setup:

```
class Comment {
    String someField        // eager
    CommentText cmntText    // lazy

    static mapping = {
      id column: 'COMMENT_ID', generator:'sequence', params:[sequence:'cmnt_seq']
}

In a separate domain class file:

class CommentText {
   String userComment
   static mapping = {
     table 'COMMENT'
     id generator:'assigned'
     userComment sqlType:'clob'
}

As noted, clob column 'user_comment' exists in the single table 'COMMENT'.
```

In 3.2.5, when doing this I get an error that column 'comment_text_id' is not defined in table 'comment'.  This didn't use to be the case, nor should the field have to exist.

On a similar note, in another case I define a composite domain class (a class defined in the same file as the actual domain class).  In this case too I get an error about a missing id:

```
class A {
    B b
}

class B {
   String someField
}
```

In this case I get an error saying that field b_id is not in table 'A'.  But - it's supposed to be embedded composition, it should not be there.

I'm building within Intellij if that is relevant.

Answer (score 1):

With GORM 6.1 this is now possible with a single domain class

```
import grails.gorm.hibernate.annotation.ManagedEntity
import static grails.gorm.hibernate.mapping.MappingBuilder.*

@ManagedEntity
class Comment {

    String someField
    String userComment

    static constraints = {
    }

    static final mapping = orm {
        id {
            generator("sequence")
            params(sequence:'cmnt_seq')
        }
        userComment = property {
            lazy(true)
            column {
                sqlType 'clob'
            }
        }
    }

}
```

Comment: I tried updating my project by changing build.gradle.  However, it cannot find the ManagedEntity import and doesn't think Comment is a domain class.  I'm not sure if Grails 3.2.5 or 3.2.8 forces a version of Gorm and that is my problem, or something else.  I assume I don't have to use the dsl version of mapping, but if I revert to the old style I can compile, but userComment is not lazy loaded.

Comment: Oh, my build.gradle:
    compile "org.grails.plugins:hibernate5:6.0.11"      // JTP
    compile "org.hibernate:hibernate-ehcache"